# Piping emails through cPanel and PHP

Tags: php, email, pipe, cpanel

I know that there have been quite a few posts floating around on this subject but I am still stuck it seems.

I have set cPanel up so that any emails that go to support@mydomain.com will be picked up and processed by a PHP script.

Now after much battling I have been able to get it to basically forward the email onto another address yet it is still bouncing the original email back to the sender too which seems weird to me. Here is the  script that I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

$email = '';

while(!feof($fd))
{
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}

fclose($fd);
mail('reciever@mytest.com', 'test', $email);
?>
```

And I have also tried to control the issue with output buffering and yes before you ask the script is chmod'd to 755...

Any help really would be appreciated as it is starting to annoy me now.

Comment: Have you fixed it yet? Are the error.log in the cPanel show anything about the error? It may possible about when pipeline in cPanel, have to put full php path and your script name.

Comment: It is not fixed yet and my error log has nothing about this email script at all :/

Comment: Well it seems like it has fixed itself now just by me leaving it alone for a few days :/

Comment: @MarcTowler Have the same issue, Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it has been malfunctioning email server in your service provider. PHP does spot if there is no mail daemon running and gives appropriate error, but it can’t do any proper error checking about mail actually delivered: after all, it might fail after a day or two and user naturally won’t wait all that time for the script to end.

Postfix updates for example often requires some care as it takes new configuration into use automatically. Or Dovecot has been updated and not restarted and it will refuse to do anything because of that by default.

Answer (score 0):

Does your cPanel not have email forwarding already? (http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/EmailFowarders)

Comment: it does but i was forwarding it onto a script to then store in a database